# Use UITextFieldDelegate for multiple fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have the following code to prevent the user from entering more than one period `.` in a `UITextField`, it works fine but I would like to do the same with other two textFields, how can this be done?

I tried assigning `delegate` to multiple fields and it doesn't quite work, it only works on the first to be comes the first responded.

```
class UserInputViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.myTextField.delegate = self
  }

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let periodsInTextField = myTextField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1

    if (periodsInTextField > 0 && string == "."){
        return false
    }
    return true
}
}
```

EDIT(Answer) : Here is how it should be done based on @ KKRocks' answer below.

```
class UserInputViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.myTextField.delegate = self
       self.secondTextField.delegate = self
       self.thirdTextField.delegate = self
  }

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let periodsInTextField = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1

    if (periodsInTextField > 0 && string == "."){
        return false
    }
    return true
 }
}
```

Comment: Give the same delegate for next textfield you can perform it easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change this line with

From :

```
let periodsInTextField = myTextField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
```

To :

```
let periodsInTextField = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
```

Comment: @ KKRocks - The delegate doesn't need to be changed `self.myTextField.delegate = self`? How assigning one textField as the delegate would work for multiple fields. Sorry but I'm not in-front of my computer to try it out.

Comment: @fs_tigre if check the delegate method `textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)` it is returning you a instance `textfield : UITextField`. This will be the same textfield which has called the delegate. You just need to do operation/change mentioned by KKRocks.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused on how delegation works, I thought that the messages sent by the delegator will only be received by whoever is assigned to be the delegate, in this case `myTextField` would be the only one that would know about those messages `myTextField` since it is the one assigned to be the delegate. Am I wrong with this statement?

Comment: @fs_tigre delegates are many-to-one. You can set 40 `UITextField`'s delegate to be self, and then when any of them have characters changing, they'll use your implementation of the delegate method.

Comment: Ah, I think you just clarified my confusion **"delegates are many-to-one"**. So, I DO need to assign each of my `textFields` as delegates in the `viewDidLoad` method `self.myTextField.delegate = self` `self.otherTextField.delegate = self` etc, correct? If yes, that solves my confusion, I misunderstood `KKRocks'` suggestion, since he only suggested to change my code in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange ` method. @ Zolnoor - Can you please confirm my statement? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Confirmed, my statement above is true, see my updated answer. Thank you all for your help.